# Closure: 'Around how much time is needed to acclimatise to dissonant Postmodern Music?'

Tags: discussion

Why was [Around how much time is needed to acclimatise to dissonant Postmodern Music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/58382/26407) closed 'as off-topic'?

It is more objective, and no more subjective or opinionated, than the following:

[Why do minor keys sound “sad”?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/3/26407) : 'sad' is a subjective adjective.

[Why are some people so paranoid about music theory?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/50713/26407) : 'paranoid' is a subjective adjective.

Comment: For some supportable reasons, subjectivity seems to be shunned around here. Some kind of tension between questions that can be answered easily and those worth asking nonetheless.

Comment: Perhaps one issue might be whether people actually agree with the premise of the question. The idea that minor keys sound sad, while a subjective observation, can still be understood to be a common perception; likewise the idea that some people are 'paranoid' about music theory. However, I'm not sure I've observed that people 'acclimatizing' to dissonant music is a common phenomenon.

Answer (score 3):

The comments to the question tell you exactly why your question was closed. I'm not going to reiterate each, but the last comment hit it exactly which is half of your question is just soliciting discussion and nothing more and does not make sense from a Q&A perspective. The specific part I'm referring to is:

> Independent of 1, please feel free to share personal experiences.

This alone just turns the whole question into a discussion that does not make sense on our site.

Another point I'll make which I state a lot on the meta is it's typically not a good format to say "X is open so Y was wrongly closed" and have that be the entire argument for reopening a question. There's  a lot of factors that go into if a question is too broad or primarily opinion based including the exact scope and phrasing of the question.

The two other question while being subjective in exact nature could at least somewhat be answered within the confines in the site even if competing answers vary.  Don't get me wrong they're not the best questions nor most objective we have on the site, but how they we asked and what they were limited to for the most part fits within our site.

Comment: `it's typically not a good format to say "X is open so Y was wrongly closed" and have that be the entire argument for reopening a question.` +1, especially because the second example is probably only open because it was so popular (and received your excellent answer) -- the exception that proves the rule, so to speak.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60796/discussion-between-topo-morto-and-dom).