# Closure: Pursuing academic research?

Tags: discussion

Location of academic research is on-topic, per [Research and studies in Melody](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/24803/26407). So why was Why was [What study argues Western listeners needing about 250 hours to acclimatise to atonal music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/58459/26407) closed as off-topic?

Comment: If you see a question that appears to be on the same topic as one of yours that has been closed, don't assume that means yours is on topic. It could just mean the other one hasn't had enough votes or flags to close it yet. Never assume it is an indicator of a good question.

Answer (score 2):

What is on-topic is largely defined [**here**](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and fleshed out on Meta.  Please read that page, all of it, as well as [Dom's answer to your other question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2796/28).

Specifically, these are off-topic:

> - requesting external resources (questions should be specific and answerable on this site; external links are for references and supporting material)
> - identifying a song, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique, chord progression, etc.