# Closures: 3 Different Questions about Xenakis

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Sorry, but I'm not certain why:

1. [Why did Xenakis compose music that 'hurt' listeners?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64527/why-did-xenakis-compose-music-that-hurt-listeners) 'closed as off-topic'?
2. [Is Xenakis's dissonant music intended to express his personal sufferings and torments?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64526/is-xenakiss-dissonant-music-intended-to-express-his-personal-sufferings-and-tor) 'closed as primarily opinion-based'?
3. [How does ignoring the math behind Xenakis's cacophonously dissonant music, affect your reaction to it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64551/how-does-ignoring-the-math-behind-xenakiss-cacophonously-dissonant-music-affec) 'closed as primarily opinion-based' ?
4. These involve music composition, history, and theory that are  covered by the [on-topic criteria](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

   > Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange is for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. If you have a question about... [...]
   >
   > practice or performance technique
   >   music theory, notation, history, or composition

   Is the hitch my writing? How can I improve?

Comment: Please actually make a case for the questions you want reopened and don't just list a bunch of questions that you think are similar and have that be the entire case for them being reopened or else it might end up like questions in the past https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/closure-pursuing-academic-research.  Most of the questions have the reasons for the closure in the comments. The ones that don't the close reason is "primary option based" which is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Note that each question is compared with the guidelines in the help center, not with other questions. It may be that the open questions you are citing should also be closed, not that yours should be reopened.

Comment: Canada - see @Todd's comment above. Your edit does not help in the slightest. It doesn't matter how many you add - they are irrelevant.

Comment: @DrMayhem  How don't they help though? The edit quotes criteria (of music composition, history) under which my question falls under. Also, is the apparent hitch truly my questions' scope, or more about me or a preference that I not ask questions here even if they meet the criteria?

Comment: It may be that all those other questions should be closed, maybe not, but trying to list a million of them does not help make yours on topic. The hitch is about the types of questions you are asking, and you don't help yourself by trying to point the finger at other ones. Please just ask questions that are on topic and in scope. It is that simple.

Comment: @DrMayhem I'm not sure if the difference between my edit and previous post has been spotted? The only difference is 4, which is a quote. Please see https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/closure-is-there-brutalist-music-composed-after-1900-that-doesnt-hurt-the-lis/2864?noredirect=1#comment6498_2864.

Comment: Canada - I'm closing these posts now, as what you are doing is editing after every comment back. That makes this more suited to chat.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70687/canada-discussion-on-closures

Comment: @DrMayhem Sorry, are Dom and you still in the chat? I haven't seen any messages from you in the past 15 minutes?

Comment: @DrMayhem We can reconvene another time, if you're busy?

Comment: Your assertion in this question is totally wrong. None of those questions involve *music history*, *music composition* and certainly not *music theory*. The first two linked questions are clearly asking about Xenakis' personal emotional mindset and motivation, which is not a historical fact, related to the *mechanics* of composition, nor even in the same universe as music theory. The third question asks us why **we** feel something and then asks us why **you** feel something. Why we feel things is literally the most subjective thing possible. Why you feel things, only you can say - we can't.

Comment: @ToddWilcox your last comment there actually gets to the heart of this issue - you've stated that these questions about motivation and listening technique don't count as music history, music composition or music theory. That might be obvious to some, less obvious to others, and others still might disagree with you, but if we can come to a consensus on the matter, then we can regard that as a useful clarification of the site's rules. *That's* how meta is supposed to work, rather than all this messy, emotional to-and-fro.

Comment: @topomorto We have already come to a consensus. That’s why the questions are closed. Five high rep users agree and as far as I’ve seen, no one disagrees (no comments to the contrary and no votes to reopen). No matter how meta is supposed to work, I don’t believe it ever will work in this situation. So I’m willing to reply to you right now but otherwise I’ve said what I intend to say.

Comment: @ToddWilcox closed questions, as you yourself have stated, don't act as a good record of what the site's rules are. A meta question acts as a much better record (even though a clarification on the on-topic page in some cases might be even better).

Comment: @topomorto In this case, the record that should be left regarding the closure of the main site question asked about here is they are off topic because they are not about music theory, practice, music history, or music composition. They are blatantly off-topic and there's no need for a legacy of meta Q&A to explain that. All it takes is five high-rep users to disagree and believe that they are on-topic to vote to re-open and that would demonstrate they are not blatantly off topic. One of them has a single up vote and none have votes to reopen.

Comment: @topomorto The record of the sites rules is kept in the help center. The interpretation of the rules (which must be done constantly, it is impossible to have rules that are always clear in all cases, which is why governments have judiciaries to interpret the laws) the interpretation of the rules is done by the community via votes up or down and votes for closure and re-opening. **It is impossible to write a set of rules that will always be clear in all cases**. To me, these cases aren't even borderline. It seems like at least three others agree these cases are clear cut.

Comment: @ToddWilcox as per my answer to https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/what-music-history-questions-are-on-and-off-topic, for at least two of the questions, I don't see that they are 'blatantly' off topic, even though I do agree that they aren't likely to get good answers.

Comment: I fully agree that "It is impossible to write a set of rules that will always be clear in all cases". It's equally true that that we don't have to let perfect be the enemy of good - we can always try for clarification where the opportunity presents itself.

Comment: I tend to feel that consensus (even qualified consensus) in meta also counts as part of a site's 'rulebook', but if you think that the help center is the sole authority, that's all the more reason to keep refining and clarifying those wordings - which is something that there seems to be a reluctance to do.

Comment: @topomorto I guess I see 4 downvotes as concensus enough. What would satisfy you? What exactly are you asking for here? Several long chats? Like 200 comments? Thorough careful answers? Cause all of that has been provided and the user who is asking for clarification actually seems to be more confused. That user also has a history of asking many questions that are just not a good fit and not what the community wants and then asking why their questions keep getting closed and refusing to understand they are asking bad questions. So I personally do not care to try to help any more.

Comment: @ToddWilcox downvotes don't represent a consensus on what the rules are. A question with 4 downvotes is almost certainly a bad question, but those downvotes in themselves don't provide clarity as to *why*. When it comes to providing clarity, I don't think quantity of communication helps, but rather, quality of communication - the ability to drill down into the logic of our rules and how they apply, and also refine them where necessary.

Comment: Specifically, I'd hoped for https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/what-music-history-questions-are-on-and-off-topic to be reopened - it has been, and I've put an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked 5 questions on meta.Music. All of them are exactly the same:

> Why did my question X get closed?

And in every case, there is a close reason listed.

When you argue that your post should remain open because another one is like it, we have repeatedly informed you that identifying another question "similar" to yours that is open does not mean yours should be open. Each question is compared against guidelines and scope on its own merits. A couple of yours may be on topic on Music Fans, but you'd need to browse the questions and scope there to check, otherwise you run the risk of having them closed there as well.

We have had multiple discussions with you about fully reading and understanding the [about] and [ask] pages. It still appears to me that you misunderstand fundamentally how the site works, and that you don't pay attention to close reasons and comments. The community keeps trying to help you, there are individuals who explain close reasons, and us mods have written a lot, but you keep doing the same things.

If you want to ask lots of questions that aren't a good fit here, it should indicate that maybe this is not the site for your sort of questions. So rather than continuing to post badly received questions and then follow up meta questions asking why they were closed, perhaps look for alternative sites on the Internet where they would fit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not sure if, and how, existing replies answer 5 overhead that I added now?

Comment: those additional 5 are also irrelevant, for the reasons already stated. **Do not measure your questions against ones which you think may be similar that aren't closed yet. Measure against our site scope**

Comment: This appears continually repeated, but it doesn't appear to address https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2872/26407.