# Closure: 'Is there Brutalist Music composed after 1900 that doesn't hurt the listener?'

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Sorry, but I'm not certain why [Is there Brutalist Music composed after 1900 that doesn't hurt the listener?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64548/is-there-brutalist-music-composed-after-1900-that-doesnt-hurt-the-listener) was closed as off-topic? Is the hitch my writing? How can I improve?

This is a question on music composition that is covered by the [on-topic criteria](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange is for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. If you have a question about... [...]
>
> music theory, notation, history, or composition

Comment: Note that each question is compared with the guidelines in the help center, not with other questions. It may be that the open questions you are citing should also be closed, not that yours should be reopened. I think your question is a better fit for https://musicfans.stackexchange.com, since that Stack is about listening to and critiquing music. This site is about the processes of making music.

Comment: Post your edit - no, your post does not meet the criteria. **Read the close reason and comments under it**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you keep changing it to have a discussion, which is what chat is for, not Q&A.

Comment: @DrMayhem I have, but they don't explain why my question isn't a question of music history or composition.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70687/canada-discussion-on-closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the close reason, and the discussions we have had with you on this subject:

> This question does not appear to be about music practice, performance, composition, technique, theory, or history within the scope defined in the help center.

The three examples you give are not analogous, despite you thinking they are, and as Todd pointed out it may be that they also are not a good fit, but whether or not they are is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal see the off-topic section "recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or __that meet particular criteria__". We're not here just to find songs that reflect certain ideas.

Comment: @DrMayhem I didn't add any unrelated post though, in my edit? I added a quote.

Comment: On this one the quote you added , your question does not meet those criteria. You have been told this over and over - the close reason included it. "that won't hurt the listener" is entirely out of scope here - it's totally down to opinion.

Comment: If you could please read the close comments you get (there are a lot) and take action accordingly, we would have to spend far less effort and you may actually get to ask more questions.