# Why was a question about compositional practice migrated to music fans?

Tags: discussion, migration

A [question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/did-john-williams-not-orchestrate-the-music-for-harry-potter) about compositional practice was migrated to music fans, even though it complies with the first two bullet points on our topics page:

> - practice or performance technique
> - music theory, notation, history, or composition

Furthermore, it is arguably off topic at music fans because music fans does not want questions about "music production":

> - Performing music, practicing music, music theory, and music production. These are instead on topic on Music:Practice & Theory

Why was this done, and what can be done to reverse it?

Comment: The link you have doesn't go to a question. The last question migrated to music fans was this one: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/87163/what-medium-did-john-williams-write-the-music-for-harry-potter . If that's the one, which is more composer/artist trivia is totally on topic on music fans and doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: @Dom yes, that's it.  Look at the answer that PiedPiper posted.  The point is that it's not trivia; it's about how the music business works.  The practice of having an orchestrator do the orchestration is completely common in both film and theater.

Comment: we also don't typically deal with pure music business questions, but I don't see it as a music business question nor practice or theory. The question can be reworded to be "What does 'orchestrated by' mean?"   which is a question that may make sense here, but seems much more like a terminology question for a consumer of music. The question as worded is very obviously about the contents of the song from a fan's perspective rather than the typical perspective we have here.

Comment: It seems to me that the question was not so much about how the music was composed or orchestrated or played or recorded, but about who did what. I would not consider "who played drums on this live version of song X" to be relevant on this site. That's just identification.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good fit at music fans - some of the better-received questions there have been along the lines of "what does this activity entail?".

The way I interpret "practice or performance technique" on our on-topic is to mean "*practice technique* or *performance technique*" - and I'd expect a 'technique' question to be asked at a greater level of detail. That might just be my personal understanding of the language.

The on-topic page might also seem to allow this as a 'history' or 'composition' question  - but when you look at how "non-technical" questions about specific works have actually been received here, I remember it as being a bit variable. Sometimes they get upvotes; sometimes it goes the other way. [What Music History questions are on- and off-topic?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/what-music-history-questions-are-on-and-off-topic) might be of some relevance.