# Why would a question about a specific composer's techniques be off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Question https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12245/in-which-of-his-works-did-mussorgsky-include-features-of-human-speech was migrated to MusicFans with the option "Not suitable for this site." I'd be curious to hear a bit more elaboration on why it didn't fit within our on-topic parameters. Granted, it could have been a bit more clear (the topic of speech-to-pitch imitation wasn't explicit), and the OP certainly could have done more homework (the question amounted to "wikipedia said ___, with a citation, and I didn't look up the citation, but I'd like to know more"). So the question isn't a great role model, but it still leaves me puzzled why it should be considered off-topic. One might imagine a better-worded, better-researched version of "I read in SourceX that ComposerY used TechniqueZ, [and for the purposes of this imaginary question I did my own research and came up empty]. Which works of ComposerY was the author of SourceX referring to? How did the composer use TechniqueZ?" This seems very different from your average "list" question, like "Can you give me some examples of Beethoven's works that are in A major." It's a narrowly-scoped question about a specific technique in the work of a specific composer.

Comment: Also, a very "meta" question: From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work it mentions a need for three votes to migrate. I'm guessing our SE allows one-vote migration?

Comment: I came very close to voting to close that question, since it is just a list question asking for titles of some pieces. Since the question was pretty specific I ended up not voting to close, but it seemed borderline to me (barely), and I can see how others might have gone the other way.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is "surely there can be a breed of 'good list question.'" Some of the worst things about "list questions" is that they engender many disparate answers that are equally valid. In this case, it sounds like maybe there are two works of Mussorgsky's that the source discusses in this context, and it would have been a mighty short list. Even "when did Steve Reich imitate speech inflections in instrumental pitches," which would be a longer list, would be objective and finite.

Comment: (Man, now it's got me really wondering "Wait, in which pieces did *Gesualdo and Monteverdi* do so? And did they really do anything different than the way we normally inflect vocal melodies to match speaking inflections?" Dangit, I'm gonna have to get that book, aren't I...)

Comment: Well, if someone asked for a list of Hendrix tunes featuring **7#9** chords, that would be a finite and shortish list, but I think that it would also be pretty clearly off-topic. Both of these questions are really thinly veiled requests to identify a song, in list form.

Comment: While there may be "good list questions", Stack Exchange as a platform really doesn't work well with them, so generally they are off topic anyway. And as for your specifics like "which works of Beethoven are in A major" that's just not a useful question within our scope anyway - how does it help with practice or performance? It would fit much better on music fans.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem That was a (straw man) example of a *bad* question. I'm having a hard time actually imagining a good one... maybe a better-researched version of the question originally referenced here. Like, someone is researching a group of works, like "Scholar X says in passing that Beethoven used an extended coda in three piano sonatas, but doesn't say which. I found one. What are the other two?" That is, the answer happens to be a "list" of multiple items, but both the question and the answer show substantive thought and research and are (theoretically) of lasting reference value.

Comment: Also, I can imagine that "list" questions could be redeemed by asking for elaboration. E.g., even the Mussorgsky question referenced here might have been saved if the question were "*How* did Mussorgsky use the 'Speech-to-song illusion.'" The answer surely would mention the works that did, but would elaborate.

Comment: @AndyBonner I will point out that a list of works and how the techniques are used are two very different questions. Editing it to be on topic vs migrating it will yield two very different sets of answers. There is nothing stopping a question about the techniques being asked now, but we need to recognize it's a very different question the OP may not necessarily want.

Comment: @AndyBonner "surely there can be a breed of 'good list question.'" - there are certainly plenty we've allowed - see edit to my answer.

Comment: @topomorto there are also very, very, very bad ones (the genre tempo list).

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the day, this question was asking for a list of songs that fit a criteria which is explicitly off-topic under our general finding lists of songs close reason hence why it was considered for migration. As for how the migration happened, since we don't have direct migration paths to any site right now outside of meta the mods had to do it. In this case I migrated it after being alerted to it by a few flags from users.

I tend to also look at questions like this as if they were asked about different musicians/artists if they would fit on this site and to me, I though of a question I think is in a similar footing which would be "Which Beetles songs include non musical sound clips in them?". To me make it pretty clear the music fan's site is more appropriate and how that "Finding pieces" close reason would make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a couple of issues here...

**Whether it's a question about music history or composition, or a bit of 'trivia'**

There's probably always going to be a bit of a fuzzy line as to whether something is about music history or composition, or just a piece of artist trivia. Some things could be either: [Pacific State - Is this out of tune, or is it a sophisticated performance playing with temperament?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/79497/pacific-state-is-this-out-of-tune-or-is-it-a-sophisticated-performance-playin) springs to mind as something that is an illustration of a compositional (or production) technique, *and* is also a bit of trivia. That question could probably live on musicfans, and it's probably fine here too.

Going back to the Mussorgsky question, Perhaps the brevity of the OP makes it hard to see how it relates to music history or composition in a substantial way.

Related: [What Music History questions are on- and off-topic?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/what-music-history-questions-are-on-and-off-topic)

**Whether it's a prohibited 'list question'**

I'm not really sure I can see why this question is a 'list question' in a way that makes it off topic.

https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask states that users should "avoid asking **subjective** questions where you are asking to list something" (emphasis mine). But it's entirely possible that answers to this question can be quite objective, if the historical documentation is there.

https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic states that questions should not be about "recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet particular criteria". But I don't think this question falls under "recommendations" in the sense that I understand it there.

Note that there many examples of questions asking for examples that fit criteria that have been well-received and remain open - here are just a very few examples, that took seconds to find:

**[Are there pieces that require retuning an instrument mid-performance?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111293/are-there-pieces-that-require-retuning-an-instrument-mid-performance)**

**[Are there J.S. Bach pieces that do not start with the tonic chord?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/86746/are-there-j-s-bach-pieces-that-do-not-start-with-the-tonic-chord)**

**[Classical examples of a 'fifth voice' or 'ghost soprano'](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11848/classical-examples-of-a-fifth-voice-or-ghost-soprano)**

**[What are the earliest examples of using the circle of fifths in western music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111458/what-are-the-earliest-examples-of-using-the-circle-of-fifths-in-western-music)**

**[Examples of jokes by Mozart](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/67753/examples-of-jokes-by-mozart)**

**[Are there any pre-20th century examples of an augmented 6th chord with a leading tone?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/66177/are-there-any-pre-20th-century-examples-of-an-augmented-6th-chord-with-a-leading)**

**[Popular examples of the ♭III in modern rock music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/115484/popular-examples-of-the-iii-in-modern-rock-music)**

Those are just a few examples, that took seconds to find. The point is often made that finding the odd example of a question that has remained open doesn't necessarily mean that such questions are generally seen as on-topic, but there are so many of these questions that this doesn't seem a relevant point here - we can see that list questions can be fine, as long as the request for a list is made as part of a substantial on-topic question (which is perhaps where the Mussorgsky question falls down).

Comment: Maybe the "subjective" point is where I was holding out hope for the notion of a "good list question." Even a list question with a rock-solid objective answer is not a terribly helpful one to posterity, but it's very different from "What are some pieces I should play next" or "What are Beethoven's best works?"

Comment: @AndyBonner yes, there are a number of quite different types of questions that could be said to ask for or elicit lists, not all of them problematic. I'm not even sure that the advice on the dont-ask page as it stands is very helpfully-worded for this site; many questions asking for advice on technique or methodology could be open to answers containing multiple suggestions, some of which may be subjective.

Comment: Right, thus the whole last bit about the notion of a "good" subjective question. I've answered several questions about "the best way to practice for X purpose," where my answer is definitely opinionated, but is substantive, not capricious or off-the-top-of-my-head, and is not a unilateral opinion unique to me. But I'm not sure there's any overlap in the Venn diagram of "good list questions" and "good subjective questions." If there's any redeeming the notion of the list, IMO it can only be when the list has one right answer.

Comment: @topomorto In our close reason we lump recommending and finding pieces together for a reason as these question are very similar in nature and have the same problem. Take the example I listed "Which Beetles songs include non musical sound clips in them?" which I think clearly demonstrates the focus on a list of songs over the techniques, theory, and practice. We are a site about making and preforming music not finding or recommending it . As Andy pointed out, a question about the how to use techniques with examples is much more inline with the goal of the site.

Comment: @Dom yep, what you say here agrees with my answer, I think. As we both say, the focus of the question is important: a question eliciting a list of musical examples as illustrations may still be a substantial question about music history or composition, but it's harder to see it as such if (as here) the request for the list is all there is in the question.

Comment: @topomorto If we agree, I don't think it's very clear from your post. We can come up with finite objective lists that touch on music history and composition, but they aren't very useful to the site as a whole and once you get into that territory, the moderation of the content needs to be well defined. To quote you: " Perhaps the brevity of the OP makes it hard to see how it relates to music history or composition in a substantial way." a  list of pieces is just a list. There's no deeper understanding to it and no explanation behind what the list means to practice, performance, or theory.

Comment: @Dom yes, that lack of depth is exactly what I am referring to when I say "the brevity of the OP makes it hard to see how it relates to music history or composition in a substantial way".

Comment: @topomorto I still don't think we do. The OP could write a novel about this in the question and I'd still feel the same if the question itself just asked for a list.  I think of it as an XY problem described on SO.  When someone asks for a list if there's a deeper source of knowledge there, then it's best to ask for that over this list itself. Asking about how to use a Speech-to-song illusion in a piece would be a great question. Asking for a list of works that do it doesn't really give anybody anything but the songs and that's what I want to hammer home.

Comment: @Dom the wording regarding list questions in my answer here isn't my own -  it's from our [on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [don't ask](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Are you saying that you don't think the wording there regarding the types of list questions that are allowed should be so tightly qualified?

Comment: @topomorto I think you are looking at the wording a bit too deeply and making an argument that doesn't actually get to the heart of the issue here. This is a request for a list of songs that fit a criteria which we always close and have an explicit close reason for (finding pieces). I don't think anyone is making the argument that it is subjective, trivia, or a recommendation, It's finding a list of pieces which we have a specific close reason for and we've closed question in the passed based on it.

Comment: @Dom It's certainly not the case that we always close requests for examples that fit criteria - see edit to my answer.

Comment: @topomorto Of course, devil's advocate, although I'm a relative newcomer I'm aware that "we've done so before" is an argument of limited weight. Seems to me the whole question is another facet of the tension between SE as "knowledge base with permanent value" (aka what we think we are) and "reference desk here to personally assist all comers" (aka what most people who wander on and ask a question think we are) :-)

Comment: @AndyBonner "we've done so before" has less weight when there are just a few examples, but that isn't the case here - there are plenty of examples of allowed and well-received list questions from all through the site's history. I think one possible description of the SE model is to become a knowledge base over time *through* the mechanism of being a reference desk - I don't think it's healthy to ignore either function.

Comment: @topomorto you are getting very close to those old meta posts that want an explanation for why 20+ questions are open. I don't think many are actually comparable to the "Finding pieces" especially since few of the answers are just that. Even the last question which IMO should still be closed, the answers don't give examples but explanations. This is what we need to talk about. Just giving a list doesn't offer the same quality and use to future users. And to add to your comment to andy, there have been very, very bad quality list questions in the past including the genre tempo question.

Comment: I just feel like at this point you are arguing something tangential to this meta post and the question being asked and as I've said before things do slip by, but our general approach is to close questions asking for finding/requesting song(s) or examples of songs. We have a close reason dedicated to it so if anything we just need to be consistent and close them.

Comment: I'd also say at least the joke one is a very, very bad example of what we should never want in a question. It's a never ending list of people's interpretations of motzart.

Comment: @Dom "Just giving a list doesn't offer the same quality and use to future users" - yes, of course - this is why more detail in a question, aiding a fuller answer, is a good thing - and why the Mussorgsky question is hard to answer well. "I just feel like at this point you are arguing something tangential to this meta post" - Well, I'm partly responding to  Andy's statement *I guess what I'm getting at is "surely there can be a breed of 'good list question.'* The site history suggests there can, and the wording of the rules as currently stated in the help center doesn't indicate otherwise.

Comment: Possibly that means there's an opportunity to clarify the rules - if so, great: that's a big part of what meta is for!

Comment: Clarification is fine, but I'd like to see the clarification, not just the suggestion there should be some. I've cited the close reason for finding and recommending pieces as that's what I've for this question not a "list bad", not "too subjective", but we don't find or commend pieces for people. If I just need to put "Finding or" in front of "recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet particular criteria" then we can do that, but again from this post I don't understand what you're aiming for.

Comment: @Dom I'm not sure what you mean by the "close reason for finding and recommending pieces" - can you point me to what you mean?

Comment: "Questions about transcribing or __finding a particular song__, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements, are off-topic since they are rarely useful to future readers." Like I've said a lot, we only get 3 close reasons. This encompasses a lot, but highlights the issue with finding/listing pieces: it doesn't have much future use. I know you may not like it, but there's limited close reasons and we need to cover a lot of ground.

Comment: @Dom interesting, I had no idea that close reason was intended to relate to 'finding examples of'-type questions - perhaps because of the wording in the singular, I always thought this close reason related only to situations where the OP wants to get the name of a single, particular song from the audio, or some partial information - which is a common off-topic request, but (I would have thought) of quite a different type and often with quite a different motivation to the kind of questions we're discussing here. I wonder how other users interpret that close reason...

Comment: One key difference between the questions I thought that related to and some other 'criteria'-based questions such as some of those above is that the latter can often be rephrased as 'Does X ever happen in music?' Or 'Does music from the period Y ever include feature X?', which could often be a genuine music history question - albeit one that might be more *naturally* phrased as *are there any examples of X?* or *What are some examples of X?*

Comment: I personally dislike broad generalizations like "does X ever happen in music" as you can pretty much guarantee yes and feels more suited for discussions than Q&A. All those questions as worded though would lead to a yes and an example which for many reasons, They don't work well due to link rot and people always being able to find another example. This is a similar reasoning to list questions being as you can always tack on to them and no answer is complete. How many examples of 'Does music from the period Y ever include feature X?' make sense as an answer and what does the site get from it

Comment: I feel this is a common discussion point between us. Just because we can allow something, does not mean it's fit for the site as is. With our core goal being able to easy place to find answers for music practice and theory questions there is a thing as too much noise to signal. We already have enough trouble finding duplicates and determining canonical questions before you consider our scope as defined includes all music and instruments not matter time span, genre, ect. We got a lot of green space left without needing to broaden anything and IMO we need to focus on what we can deliver best.

Comment: @Dom Certainly we're in familiar territory there, and in turn I'm sure you remember my familiar responses to those points!